# Get session value from a while loop

Tags: php, ajax, session

I am currently having a php script like this:

```
function a()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if($_SESSION["check"] == 0)
            {                     
                 page_close()//function runs when page closed
                 break;
            }
            $_SESSION["check"] = 0;
            sleep(2);                   
        }
   }
```

and another function named b which is called by ajax after every half second to check if the page at browser was closed or not:

```
function b()
  {
     $_SESSION["check"]=1;   
  }
```

The problem is that $_SESSION["check"] in function a always return value 0 even after the function b is called so many times. Wondering if variable is locked in function while executing. If it is true, what is the best way to detect the $_SESSION["check"] was changed by other functions in while loop like that.
Thank you :D

Comment: start session first `session_start()`

Comment: I had run the session_start() function before that.

Comment: You have to write $_SESSION["check"]=1;  in if statement. or call function b() in if statement before break;.

Comment: But the function b is called by ajax from client every half second to check the connection with browser. If i put b in if statement before break, it is like running another function and has no connection with client at all.  :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Because session is locked to an executing script so other scripts can not change the value of the session and might lead to unexpected results. But if you want to change session variable when other scripts are using the session, you can use function session_start() right before changing and close session immediately after that by function session_write_close().